# android - Теxtview not change instantly

Tags: java, android, textview

I accept the array from the server, and then fill the data textview.

```
private class ReadMessages extends       AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer>
{
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    String ansver, bfr_st;
    JSONArray JsonArray;
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
        String post_url = server_name +"/chat.php?action=select";
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(post_url).openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000); 
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); //канал
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")); //буфер
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //сборщик строки
        while ((bfr_st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(bfr_st); //получили массив в виде string
        }

        String json_bum = sb.toString(); 
        JsonArray = new JSONArray(json_bum); //преобразовали string обратно в массив

        for (int i=0; i<JsonArray.length(); i++) { 
             jsonObject = JsonArray.getJSONObject(i); //вынули все обьекты
        }
        tv_number.setText("Номер     - " + jsonObject.getInt("_id") + 
                    "\n"
                      + "Автор -      " + jsonObject.getString("author") +
                      "\n" 
                      + "Адресат     - " + jsonObject.getString("client") +
                      "\n"
                      + "Время -      " + jsonObject.getLong("data") +
                      "\n"
                      + "Текст - "      + jsonObject.getString("text") +
                      "\n");

            is.close();
            br.close();

            } catch (Exception e) { 

            } finally { 

                conn.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }


        }
```

when I fold the application and then come back to it the text changes . but immediately when you press a button that does not happen

Comment: you are calling a server, so you should wait until have a respond from it, and It depends in a lot of different factors to think that is going to be immediately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not allowed to update GUI on a separate thread. You should update it in the `OnPostExecute` within your `AsyncTask`. Also, you must `@Override` the `doInBackground`.

```
private class ReadMessages extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Integer> {
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    String ansver, bfr_st;
    JSONArray JsonArray;

    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
        String post_url = server_name +"/chat.php?action=select";
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(post_url).openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000); 
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.connect();

        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream(); //канал
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8")); //буфер
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); //сборщик строки
        while ((bfr_st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(bfr_st); //получили массив в виде string
        }

        String json_bum = sb.toString(); 
        JsonArray = new JSONArray(json_bum); //преобразовали string обратно в массив

        for (int i=0; i<JsonArray.length(); i++) { 
             jsonObject = JsonArray.getJSONObject(i); //вынули все обьекты
        }
            is.close();
            br.close();

            } catch (Exception e) { 

            } finally { 

                conn.disconnect();
            }
            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
           tv_number.setText("Номер     - " + jsonObject.getInt("_id") + 
                  "\n"
                    + "Автор -      " + jsonObject.getString("author") +
                    "\n" 
                    + "Адресат     - " + jsonObject.getString("client") +
                    "\n"
                    + "Время -      " + jsonObject.getLong("data") +
                    "\n"
                    + "Текст - "      + jsonObject.getString("text") +
                    "\n");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can only update your GUI elements/widgets from app main thread. AsyncTask is creating seperate thread and you can't do this from method `doInBackground`, try use `publishProgress` and `onProgressUpdate` or do all this staff in `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 0):

Why you decided it must be immediately ? It depends on your internet speed, ping and etc. Good practice is using progressBar to show user that something is happening, not just empty screen and then textView appears after several seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The line in doInbackground:

```
tv_number.setText("Номер     - " + jsonObject.getInt("_id") + 
                    "\n"
                      + "Автор -      " + jsonObject.getString("author") +
                      "\n" 
                      + "Адресат     - " + jsonObject.getString("client") +
                      "\n"
                      + "Время -      " + jsonObject.getLong("data") +
                      "\n"
                      + "Текст - "      + jsonObject.getString("text") +
                      "\n");
```

actually throws an exception, but the empty catch statement prevents the app from crashing.

you can't update views from a background thread, updating UI must be on the UI thread. In case of AsyncTask you can do this in **onPostExecute** or **onProgressUpdate** methods.

change your doInBackground implementation, make it return a String:

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... params){
}
```

then in onPostExecute, update the textview

```
protected onPostExecute(String result){
tv_number.setText(result);
}
```